# self.inicio = self.adding += 1 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, clase, sum

Soy nuevo en python y me sale este error, por favor ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Este es mi código:

```
import time

class Prueba:
     def __init__(self):
         self.inicio = 0
         self.adding = 10
     
     def Function(self):
         self.inicio = self.adding += 1 
         time.sleep(1)
         print(self.inicio)


root = Prueba()
root.Function()
```

Y este es el error:

```
    self.inicio = self.adding += 1 
                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Falta que agregues el error

Comment: self.inicio = self.adding += 1 
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: este es el error perdon soy nuevo

Comment: sera solo el mas? que trataste de hacer?

Comment: no entiendo porfavor

Comment: Tienes dos signos de igualdad en una misma expresión. Si querías asignarle a `inicio` el valor de `adding` + `1`, entonces la sintaxis es: `self.inicio = self.adding + 1`. Si querías asignarle a `inicio` su mismo valor actual + `adding` + `1`, entonces la expresión es `self.inicio += self.adding + 1`

Comment: muchas gracias  por quitarme ese error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás vengas de `c` o lenguajes similares, dónde una expresión de asignación retorna el valor mismo que se está asignando. En *python* eso no ocurre.

Por ejemplo en c:

```c
a = 5
```

Retorna 5, y por tanto, podemos encadenar asignaciones de la forma:

```c
b = a = 5
```

Donde a b le asignamos el valor que retorna la asignación `a = 5`, es decir, también `5`. De la misma forma podríamos imprimir el valor retornado por la asignación:

```c
printf("Valor de la asignación: %d", a = 5)
```

En python (y muchos otros lenguajes que no derivan de `c`), sin embargo, una asignación no retorna nada. La expresión de impresión igual dará un error:

```
print(self.adding += 1)
```

```
    print(self.adding += 1)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

El error lo da en el símbolo `+` puesto que luego de la variable, espera una coma con otra variable o el paréntesis de cierre.

Por lo mismo, debes realizar cada asignación por separado, si quieres asignarle a inicio el nuevo valor de adding, tienes que hacer:

```
self.adding += 1
self.inicio = self.adding
```

Comment: muchas gracias que litle jesus te lo pague mucho

Comment: @Mike, Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí por una búsqueda a identificar que la respuesta fue de ayuda. Utiliza esta técnica también cuando hagas investigaciones y caigas a StackOverflow, pues fácilmente puedes identificar, cuando hay varias respuestas, cuál es la que le ha servido a quien planteó originalmente el problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].

Comment: perdon como lo hago perdon

Comment: Está explicado en el [tour] o en [que hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).